# SQL group by with a count

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table (simplified below)

```
|company|name |age|
| 1     |  a  | 3 | 
| 1     |  a  | 3 | 
| 1     |  a  | 2 | 
| 2     |  b  | 8 | 
| 3     |  c  | 1 | 
| 3     |  c  | 1 |
```

For various reason the age column should be the same for each company. I have another process that is updating this table and sometimes it put an incorrect age in. For company 1 the age should always be 3

I want to find out which companies have a mismatch of age.

Ive done this

```
select company, name age from table group by company, name, age
```

but dont know how to get the rows where the age is different. this table is a lot wider and has loads of columns so I cannot really eyeball it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What is the rule that causes `company=1` to have `age=1`? How do you find a mismatch?

Comment: Note: this can also be solved with a self-join.

Comment: @user2246674 why do you need to join?

Comment: @491243 You don't. "[T]his can *also* be solved with a self-join." There is more than one way to skin a cat. Using a join is the way such RA queries - "are there duplicates?" - are often taught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be including `age` in the group by clause.

```
SELECT  company
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY company, name
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT age) <> 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cefc/1)

Comment: I think it's possible to group only by company, no name needed there

Comment: @RomanPekar IMO it needs to have `name` on the group by clause since company may have many employees. *btw, it's only an assumption*

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "how to get **the rows** where the age is different" and not just the comapnies:

Add a unique row id (a primary key) if there isn't already one. Let's call it `id`.

Then, do

```
select id from table 
where company in 
    (select company from table 
    group by company 
    having count(distinct age)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the row(s) with a different age than the max-count age of each company/name group:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select company, name, age,
           maxAge=(select top 1 age
             from dbo.table1 t2
             group by company,name, age
             having( t1.company=t2.company and t1.name=t2.name)
             order by count(*) desc)
    from dbo.table1 t1 
)
select * from cte 
where age <> maxAge
```

<kbd>[**Demontration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37c32/21/0)</kbd>

If you want to update the incorrect with the correct ages you just need to replace the `SELECT` with `UPDATE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select company, name, age,
           maxAge=(select top 1 age
             from dbo.table1 t2
             group by company,name, age
             having( t1.company=t2.company and t1.name=t2.name)
             order by count(*) desc)
    from dbo.table1 t1 
)
UPDATE cte SET AGE = maxAge 
WHERE age <> maxAge
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37c32/23/0)</kbd>